# Procedure and pointers C

Tags: c

im trying to make a procedure to find a maximum numbers out of 3, which i will assign later to another variable pointer in main program

```
int Maximum (int *a, int *b, int *c)
{

if (*a>=*b)
{
    if (*a<*c)
    {*a=*c;}
}
else
{
    *a=*b;
    if (*a<*c)
       {*a=*c;}
}
return a;
}
```

compiler giving me error that "expected 'int*' but argument is of type 'int' "
so i changes that part to

```
int * Maximum (int *a, int *b, int *c)
```

but error sentence still same ?

Comment: Well, if this is too much, do something simpler first. Maybe write a function that finds the maximum out of *one* input?

Comment: im relatively new with programming especially with C, im sure the logic is right but "how are you supposed to put that" still confuse me

Comment: C does not support _procedures_ in the Pascal/Modula sense, but all callables are _functions_. Your callable would be actually a function in all languages, as it apparently returns a result. And why do you use pointers? You seem to have some missconceptions. Read your C book or ask your teacher to elaborate.

Comment: @KerrekSB: **One**? Isn't that too simple?

Comment: @Olaf i am using pointer because ill use pointer p `p = maximum(a,b,c)` which was giving me error.

Comment: @Olaf: No. Nothing is too simple if it can give you *some* confidence that you're understanding some aspect of the problem.

Comment: @Cleansy: Just because you use that does not mean it is correct. I strongly doubt that. Maximum is a temporal snapshot. If you return a pointer to the max. object **at that time**, the object changes lateron, the maximum condition does not hold true anymore. So returning a pointer is somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your original function is designed to return an `int` and you're returning `a`, which is an `int` *pointer.* Either return the `int` (`*a)`, or change the function so it returns an `int *`.

However, based on your actual message:

> expected 'int*' but argument is of type 'int'

and the fact you state you've *made* that change and still have the problem (note the word "argument" in the message), this indicates that the problem lies not with the return value but with the way you're passing the arguments to it.

You are actually passing `int` where the function expects `int *` and that's probably caused by you using something like:

```
int one = 3;
int two = 7;
int three = 42;
int maxOfThree = Maximum (one, two, three);
```

If you wanted to pass *pointers* to the function, you would need:

```
Maximum (&one, &two, &three);
```

(passing the pointers to the variables, not the values of them).

A better solution (more readable and with correct data types both going in to, and coming out of, the function) to your problem would probably be:

```
int Maximum (int a, int b, int c) {
    if ((a > b) && (a > c))
        return a;
    if (b > c)
        return b;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: thats basically what i note, i already add '* maximum' and for some reason compiler gives same error sentence

Comment: yup this way was better,ty. but compiler still giving the very exact error

Comment: @Cleansy, read the update, it's to do with what you're passing in, not what you're getting out.